# ASP NET Caching

Tags: asp.net

I am fairly new to ASP.NET and developing a website portal for my boss to monitoring progress of work.

While doing this I Am facing the following difficulty

I have page with ASP Menu Control with few pages is linked to the Menu Items.
Now on My Home page I have some Tables Charts and Grid View which are linked with a text box for fetching SQL select parameter.

Now the scenario is I opened the website at home page I entered a value in Textbox

example : "X" in text Box  and got the values "Y"of other controls based on the value of Textbox !!!! Fine

If I click on the other menu item its page loads and if click back on Home Page tab/menu item the home page loads in its default state with text box empty and other items as default value

Here What I want is to load my last Home page State i.e. x as Text Box Values and Y as other value

I tried using cache functionality of the page Nothing worked.

Please Help

Thanks in anticipation!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one of the followings to store a current user's history/preferences -

- [Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) - Easy to implement.
- Cache - You will need to append current logged-in user's Id in front of cache key, because Cache is available for all users.
- Database - Most reliable way but it requires a few extra work.